# Configure metallb with kubernetes running on different vps servers

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, devops, vps, metallb

I have a running Kubernetes cluster consists of 3 nodes and one mater running on a VPS server, each node and master has its own public IP and floating IP also assigned to it and all these IPs are different from other

I am trying to configure metallb as a load balancer for my Kubernetes cluster but I don't know how can I set the metalLb IPs to range in the configuration file

here are the IPs examples of my servers

- 115.203.150.255
- 94.217.238.58
- 46.12.5.65
- 76.47.79.44

as you can see here, each IP is different so how can I set the Ip ranges in metallb config map?

Here an example of a config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - PUBLIC_IP-PUBLIC_IP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Metallb documentation there is a mention you can use certain IPs `metallb.universe.tf/address-pool`. See [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/#requesting-specific-ips)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: production-public-ips
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The `production-public-ips` must be configured as showed [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/example/).

To [configure MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration), you should create a configmap with your ips. Since you don't have the range, you can set `/32` as subnet for your ips, like the example below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: production-public-ips
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 115.203.150.255/32
      - 94.217.238.58/32
      - 46.12.5.65/32
      - 76.47.79.44/32
```

It should work for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think these steps come after configuring metal lb, so before this, I want to configure metal lb so how can I add the IPs ranges in metallb config

Comment: @tareksalem I've updated my answer with the relevant configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with VPS in different countries, but NGINX ingress controller bare metal considerations doesn't allow IP NODE as IP/32 range in "addresses".

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

> MetalLB requires a pool of IP addresses in order to be able to take
> ownership of the ingress-nginx Service. This pool can be defined in a
> ConfigMap named config located in the same namespace as the MetalLB
> controller. This pool of IPs must be dedicated to MetalLB's use, you
> can't reuse the Kubernetes node IPs or IPs handed out by a DHCP
> server.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30372403)